# How can I make a variable take only one of certain values in Swift 5

Tags: swift

I'm using Swift5 and I want to do something like:

```
class trafficLight{
var state: String       // state can be one of "red", "blue", "yellow"
...
}
```

I want the state variable to be either `"red"` `"blue"` or `"yellow"` and nothing else.  `"red"` `"blue"` and `"yellow"` don't necessarily be a String.
Is such thing possible?

Comment: Try to learn it from the basic first: https://codewithchris.com/swift-enum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use an enum:

```
class TrafficLight {
    enum State {
        case red
        case blue
        case yellow
    }

    var state: State
}
```

Comment: `enum`! thank you, that's just what I was looking for..!